# can't uninstall Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I am trying to uninstall the update 4. The 'visual studio' window appears and suddenly stops working. how can I uninstall it? i have tried revo uninstaller but it didn't work. the update doesn't appear in the programs and features list anymore because revo "uninstalled" it.